# Computing convolution

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

I need to compute the convolution of these two functions:

$h(t)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-t}},$ $g(t) =e^{-t}p(e^{-t}),$ $t=ln(H)$

I understand how to do it when I ignore the substitution $t=ln(H)$. However, after I substitute $t$ with $ln(H)$, how can I compute the convolution?

When I convolve these two functions, I need to do $h(t-\tau)$ and $g(\tau)$. How does the substitution change this?

Does it become $h(ln(H)-\tau)$ and $g(ln(\tau))$)? or something else?

Thanks so much for help

Comment: $p$ is just a probability distribution that is dependent on $t$ and H is a variable

Comment: In my opinion, you just have to consider $H$ as the new variable, hence it will become $H - \tau$.